# What's the most efficient way to tell if a single character is alphanumeric in PHP?

Tags: php

What's the most efficient way to tell if a single character is alphanumeric in PHP?

I know I could do something like:

```
function isSingleAlphaNum($chr){
    if(!is_string($chr){
        return false;
    }

    //capture the first alphanumeric character, replace the whole string with it
    $test = preg_replace('#([a-zA-Z0-9]{1}).*#','$1',$chr);
    if($test == $chr){
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```

This seems clunky. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good 'ol ctype_alnum() 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php

```
ctype_alnum($chr);
```

Comment: interesting. must have had a brain fart. this is exactly what i need.

Answer (score 2):

What about [`ctype-alnum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php)?